# Avoid showing Abbreviations in the Glossary with Only a Single Use

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, glossaries-extra

I am eperimenting with the glossaries-extra package and use bib2gls. Currently every abbreviation used in my document via `\gls` (for example `\gls{gpu}`) shows the full form on first use (that I like) but also generates an entry in the glossary, even if the abbreviation is used only exactly once.

Reading the documentation and usage guides on glossaries and glossaries-extra have not helped me in this regard. From my previous experience, the package acro has a package option `single=true` to achieve this but maybe you have a solution before I consider switching (at least for abbreviations).

### Question

Is it possible to omit single uses of abbreviations from the glossary (shown via `\printunsrtglossaries` for example)?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way to filter the output of `\printunsrtglossaries` via the `printunsrtglossaryhandler` hook.

This particular solution requires the bib2gls with the extra parameter `--record-count`: `bib2gls --record-count <filename>`.

Adding this to the preamble will then filter by record count:

```
\renewcommand{\printunsrtglossaryhandler}[1]{%
  \ifthenelse{\GlsXtrTotalRecordCount{#1}>1}%
  {\glsxtrunsrtdo{#1}}%
  {}%
}
```

EDIT:
A significant drawback is the compilation failure in case the resulting glossary is empty.